# Using SNS as a Target to Trigger Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Lambda function is working 100%, i set my Cloudwatch rule and connected the Target to the Lambda directly and everything is working fine.
My manager want me to change the Target in the Cloudwatch and set it to SNS, then use the SNS as a trigger in my Lambda.
I have done the necessary thing and now my Lambda Function is no longer working.

```
import os, json, boto3

def validate_instance(rec_event):
    sns_msg = json.loads(rec_event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])

    account_id = sns_msg['account']
    event_region = sns_msg['region']

    assumedRoleObject = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::{}:role/{}".format(account_id, 'VSC-Admin-Account-Lambda-Execution-Role'),
        RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
    )

    credentials = assumedRoleObject['Credentials']
    print(credentials)

    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', event_region, aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
                              aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
                              aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
                              )

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ip_permissions=[]
    print("The event log is " + str(event))
    # Ensure that we have an event name to evaluate.
    if 'detail' not in event or ('detail' in event and 'eventName' not in event['detail']):
        return {"Result": "Failure", "Message": "Lambda not triggered by an event"}
    elif event['detail']['eventName'] == 'AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress':
        items_ip_permissions = event['detail']['requestParameters']['ipPermissions']['items']
        security_group_id=event['detail']['requestParameters']['groupId']
        print("The total items are " + str(items_ip_permissions))
        for item in items_ip_permissions:
            s = [val['cidrIp'] for val in item['ipRanges']['items']]
            print("The value of ipranges are " + str(s))
            if ((item['fromPort'] == 22 and item['toPort'] == 22) or (item['fromPort'] == 143 and item['toPort'] == 143) or (item['fromPort'] == 3389 and item['toPort'] == 3389)) and ('0.0.0.0/0' in [val['cidrIp'] for val in item['ipRanges']['items']]):
                print("Revoking the security rule for the item" + str(item))
                ip_permissions.append(item)
        result = revoke_security_group_ingress(security_group_id,ip_permissions)
    else:
        return 

def revoke_security_group_ingress(security_group_id,ip_permissions):
    print("The security group id is " + str(security_group_id))
    print("The ip_permissions value to be revoked is " + str(ip_permissions))
    ip_permissions_new=normalize_paramter_names(ip_permissions)
    response = boto3.client('ec2').revoke_security_group_ingress(GroupId=security_group_id,IpPermissions=ip_permissions_new)
    print("The response of the revoke is " + str(response))

def normalize_paramter_names(ip_items):
    # Start building the permissions items list.
    new_ip_items = []

    # First, build the basic parameter list.
    for ip_item in ip_items:

    new_ip_item = {
        "IpProtocol": ip_item['ipProtocol'],
        "FromPort": ip_item['fromPort'],
        "ToPort": ip_item['toPort']
    }

    # CidrIp or CidrIpv6 (IPv4 or IPv6)?
    if 'ipv6Ranges' in ip_item and ip_item['ipv6Ranges']:
        # This is an IPv6 permission range, so change the key names.
        ipv_range_list_name = 'ipv6Ranges'
        ipv_address_value = 'cidrIpv6'
        ipv_range_list_name_capitalized = 'Ipv6Ranges'
        ipv_address_value_capitalized = 'CidrIpv6'
    else:
        ipv_range_list_name = 'ipRanges'
        ipv_address_value = 'cidrIp'
        ipv_range_list_name_capitalized = 'IpRanges'
        ipv_address_value_capitalized = 'CidrIp'

    ip_ranges = []

    # Next, build the IP permission list.
    for item in ip_item[ipv_range_list_name]['items']:
        ip_ranges.append(
            {ipv_address_value_capitalized: item[ipv_address_value]}
        )

    new_ip_item[ipv_range_list_name_capitalized] = ip_ranges

    new_ip_items.append(new_ip_item)

    return new_ip_items
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume the permissions are missing causing the invocation failure.

You need to explicitly grant permission for SNS to invoke the Lambda function.

Below is the CLI

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name my-function --action lambda:InvokeFunction --statement-id sns-my-topic \
--principal sns.amazonaws.com --source-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789012:my-topic
```

my-function -> Name of the lambda function

my-topic -> Name of the SNS topic

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html